# Установка новой OC и удаление старой.

Tags: linux

Как установить OC AltLinux LXDesktop 6.0 версия lite если на компьютере стоит windows xp ?

Answer (score 1):

1. стартуем с КД с линуксом или с загрузочной флешки.
2. если в этом дистрибутиве имеется gparted, то
    2.1. - гпартедом сносим напрочь нтфс разделы и делаем переразметку - первый раздел для системы 20гб (экст3 или экст4), второй раздел - под своп (не менее объема оперпамяти, можно больше), третий раздел - под папку /home - все остальное место диска (экст3 или экст4)
3. ставим систему пошагово, согласно программы установки дистрибутива
4. если гпартеда в дистрибутиве нет, то делаем п.2.1 с любого аварийного загрузочного диска, на котором имеется акронис диск директор или что-то похожее